# После окончания работы программа крашится при вызове деструктора

Tags: c++, объекты, матрицы, ссылки, деструктор

Matrix.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

class DynamicMatrix 
{
public:
    DynamicMatrix();
    DynamicMatrix(int rows, int cols);
    DynamicMatrix(const DynamicMatrix& other);
    ~DynamicMatrix();

    void WriteToBinary(ofstream& file);
    void ReadFromBinary(ifstream& file);
    void SortArrayX(int k);
    void SortArrayY(int k);
    int** FindElement(int x);
    int ReplaceElement(int x, int y, int Number);


    DynamicMatrix Sum(const DynamicMatrix& other);
    DynamicMatrix Sub(const DynamicMatrix& other);

    void operator () (int x, int y, int Number);
    DynamicMatrix& operator = (const DynamicMatrix& other);
    int* operator [] (int index);


    int GetRows();
    int GetCols();
    int GetElement(int rows, int cols);
    char* ToString();


private:
    int** arr;
    int rows_;
    int cols_;

    friend DynamicMatrix operator + (const DynamicMatrix& FirstMatrix, const DynamicMatrix& SecondMatrix);
    friend DynamicMatrix operator - (const DynamicMatrix& FirstMatrix, const DynamicMatrix& SecondMatrix);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, DynamicMatrix& matrix);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, DynamicMatrix& matrix);
};
```

Matrix.cpp

```
#include "Matrix.h"

DynamicMatrix::DynamicMatrix(int rows, int cols) : rows_(rows), cols_(cols) {
    arr = new int* [rows];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[cols];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

}

DynamicMatrix::DynamicMatrix(const DynamicMatrix& other) : rows_(other.rows_), cols_(other.cols_) {
    arr = new int* [rows_];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows_; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[cols_];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < rows_; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols_; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = other.arr[i][j];
        }
    }

}

DynamicMatrix::DynamicMatrix() : DynamicMatrix(0, 0) {}

DynamicMatrix::~DynamicMatrix() {

    for (int i = 0; i < rows_; i++) {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }

    delete[] arr;
}

int DynamicMatrix::GetElement(int Rows, int Rols) {
        return arr[Rows][Rols];
}
int DynamicMatrix::GetRows() {
    return rows_;
}

int DynamicMatrix::GetCols() {
    return cols_;
}

char* DynamicMatrix::ToString() {
    char* string = new char[rows_ * cols_ * 4];

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols_; ++j) {
            int length = snprintf(string + index, (rows_ * cols_ * 4) - index, "%d ", arr[i][j]);
            index += length;
        }
        string[index++] = '\n';
    }
    string[index] = '\0';

    return string;
}

void DynamicMatrix::SortArrayX(int k) {

    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < cols_; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols_ - 1; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[k][j] > arr[k][j + 1])
            {
                temp = arr[k][j];
                arr[k][j] = arr[k][j + 1];
                arr[k][j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void DynamicMatrix::SortArrayY(int k) {

    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows_; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows_ - 1; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[j][k] > arr[j + 1][k])
            {
                temp = arr[j][k];
                arr[j][k] = arr[j + 1][k];
                arr[j + 1][k] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int** DynamicMatrix::FindElement(int x) {
    int** result = new int* [rows_ * cols_ * 2];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (rows_ * cols_ * 2 - 1); i++) {
        result[i] = new int[2];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows_; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols_; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == x) {
                result[count][0] = i;
                result[count][1] = j;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int DynamicMatrix::ReplaceElement(int x, int y, int Number) {
    if (x >= 0 && y >= 0) {
        return arr[x][y] = Number;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

DynamicMatrix DynamicMatrix::Sum(const DynamicMatrix& other) {
    if (rows_ == other.rows_ && cols_ == other.cols_) {
        DynamicMatrix result(rows_, cols_);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows_; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols_; j++) {
                result[i][j] = arr[i][j] + other.arr[i][j];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

DynamicMatrix DynamicMatrix::Sub(const DynamicMatrix& other) {
    if (rows_ == other.rows_ && cols_ == other.cols_) {
        DynamicMatrix result(rows_, cols_);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows_; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols_; j++) {
                result[i][j] = arr[i][j] - other.arr[i][j];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    else {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "Matrix have different size :";
        throw std::invalid_argument(stream.str().c_str());
    }
}

int* DynamicMatrix::operator [] (int index) {
    return arr[index];
}

DynamicMatrix& DynamicMatrix::operator = (const DynamicMatrix& other) {
    if (&other != this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows_; i++) {
            delete[] arr[i];
        }

        delete[] arr;

        rows_ = other.rows_;
        cols_ = other.cols_;


        arr = new int* [rows_];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows_; i++) {
            arr[i] = new int[cols_];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows_; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols_; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = other.arr[i][j];
            }
        }

    }

    return *this;
}

void DynamicMatrix::operator () (int x, int y, int Number) {
    ReplaceElement(x, y, Number);
}

DynamicMatrix operator + (const DynamicMatrix& FirstMatrix, const DynamicMatrix& SecondMatrix) {
    DynamicMatrix Matrix(FirstMatrix);

    return Matrix.Sum(SecondMatrix);

}

DynamicMatrix operator - (const DynamicMatrix& FirstMatrix, const DynamicMatrix& SecondMatrix) {
    DynamicMatrix Matrix(FirstMatrix);

    return Matrix.Sub(SecondMatrix);

}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, DynamicMatrix& matrix) {

    out << matrix.rows_ << " " << matrix.cols_ << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows_; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.cols_; j++) {
            out << matrix.arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        out << endl;
    }

    return out;
}

istream& operator >> (istream& in, DynamicMatrix& matrix) {

    in >> matrix.rows_ >> matrix.cols_;

    matrix.arr = new int* [matrix.rows_];
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows_; ++i) {
        matrix.arr[i] = new int[matrix.cols_];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows_; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.cols_; j++) {
            in >> matrix.arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    return in;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
DynamicMatrix Matrix1(5, 5);
DynamicMatrix Matrix2;

ofstream write;
ifstream read;

write.open("Matrix.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
if (!write.is_open()) {
    cout << "File error!" << endl;
    return 1;
}
else {
    write.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Matrix1), sizeof(DynamicMatrix)); 
    write.close();
}

read.open("Matrix.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
if (!read.is_open()) {
    cout << "File error!" << endl;
    return 1;
}
else {
    read.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Matrix2), sizeof(DynamicMatrix));
    read.close();
}

cout << Matrix2;
```

Значит хочу я в файл записать, вроде записывается, но программа крашит после завершения. Я вот дебаггером прошелся, увидел то что у нас деструктор второго объекта вызывается для того же адреса что и при первом вызове деструктора, но не могу понять как исправить, помогите пожалуйста!!!!

Comment: Вы записали в файл не данные, вы записали в файл значения трех полей (`int** arr;
    int rows_;
    int cols_;`). Соответственно и считали из файла указатель на то же место в памяти. А если б вы записали, а в другой программе прочли — полная задница наступила бы куда быстрее :)

Comment: @Harry а как сделать иначе?

Comment: А вы читали ответы по ссылке-дубликату?... Нужны свои функции записи и чтения.